# String SVG not loading angular variables

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following svg image in string format

```
image = `<svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->
  <g>
   <title>background</title>
   <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
   <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
    <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <title>Layer 1</title>
   <rect id="svg_5" height="82" width="169" y="60.5" x="31" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
   <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_6" height="83.999999" width="179" y="56.5" x="347" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#fff"/>
   <rect id="svg_7" height="84" width="171" y="251.5" x="34" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
   <rect stroke="#000" id="svg_8" height="83.999997" width="186" y="247.5" x="352" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#fff"/>
   <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_9" y="109.5" x="72" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">{{data['301']}}</text>
   <text style="cursor: move;" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_10" y="107.5" x="393" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">{{data['301']}}</text>
   <text style="cursor: move;" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_11" y="300.5" x="70" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">{{data['301']}}</text>
   <text style="cursor: move;" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_12" y="296.5" x="399" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">{{data['301']}}</text>
   <ellipse ry="45" rx="77.5" id="svg_13" cy="209.5" cx="283.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
   <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_14" y="212.5" x="266" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">{{data['301']}}</text>
  </g>
 </svg>`;
```

I did following steps to load this image in angular

In ts file

```
data = {301: 0}
@ViewChild('container', { static: true, read: ElementRef }) container: ElementRef;
this.container.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.image;
```

In html file

```
 <div #container></div>
```

I want to load this image in my html. It is loading but it is showing angular variables also in string format.

[image]

Comment: Angular will not do anything with fragments that are included using innerHtml. Angular does support svg components though where your template can be an svg. That is probably your solution. More: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-svg-files-as-component-templates-with-angular-cli-ea58fe79b6c1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the data in the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<div [innerHTML]="innerHTML"></div>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {
  innerHTML: SafeHtml;

  constructor(
    private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  ) {
    // data from server
    const { data, svg } = {
      data: {
        '301': 'some text',
      },
      svg: '<svg viewBox="0 0 500 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\
        <text x="10" y="20" >example: ${ data["301"] } count: ${ count }</text>\
      </svg>',
    };

    let count = 0;
    this._addSvg(data, svg, count);

    setInterval(
      () => {
        count += 1;
        this._addSvg(data, svg, count);
        this._cdr.detectChanges();
      },
      3000,
    )
  }

  private _addSvg(data: any, svg: string, count: number): void {
    const evalSvg = eval('`' + svg + '`');
    this.innerHTML = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(evalSvg);
  }
}
```

Documentation: [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

from angular 8+ you can use svg as a template:

**svg.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-svg',
  templateUrl: './svg.component.svg',
  styleUrls: ['./svg.component.scss'],
})
export class SvgComponent {
  @Input() textLine1: string;
  @Input() textLine2: string;
}
```

**svg.component.svg:**

```
<svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  ...
  <g>
    <text ...>{{ textLine1 }}</text>
    <text ...>{{ textLine2 }}</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**and implementation:**

```
<app-svg
  [testLine1]="data[301]"
  [textLine2]="data['otherInput']"
></app-svg>
```

Comment: It is working but I want to change this data every 3 sec. So how we can do that?

Comment: what version of angular do you use?

Comment: Angular version 8

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I have multiple svg in my database for every user has different svg so how can I load that svg template in svg aap component?

Comment: attach the function that will change the data

Comment: Right now I'm using 

`var count = 0
    setInterval(()=>{
      count=count+1
      this.data["301"] = count
      console.log(this.data)
      // this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
      // this.container.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.image;
    }, 3000)`